# Get keys for maximum value from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of type

```
Dictionary<int, GValue>
```

where GValue is an object that contains two double values P1 and P2

I am trying to get key for maximum values from dictinary using follwing code

```
var keyForMaxP1 = dict.Keys.Aggregate((i, j) => dict[i].P1 >= dict[j].P1 ? i : j);
var keyForMaxP2 = dict.Keys.Aggregate((i, j) => dict[i].P2 >= dict[j].P2 ? i : j);
```

It gives me keys for max P1 and P2 Correctly.

But what if dictinary contains more than one key with max P1 Or P2 Value ??
Here it still returning one Key which comes first during traversing of dictinary.

**Edit**

Suppose dictionary have values P1 with max value say 3.52. Now if there are two entries in dictionary with value P1  = 3.52, I wanna to get both the keys related to this value

Comment: I do not understand. Give an example of what you want vs what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all `KeyValuPairs` with a max-value you can use `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var MaxP1KeyValues = dict.GroupBy(kv => kv.Value.P1)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).First();
var MaxP2KeyValues = dict.GroupBy(kv => kv.Value.P2)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).First();

foreach (var kv in MaxP1KeyValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value-P1:{1}", kv.Key, kv.Value.P1);
}
foreach (var kv in MaxP2KeyValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value-P2:{1}", kv.Key, kv.Value.P2);
}
```

This groups all `KeyValuePair<int, GValue>` in the dictionary by the value of P1/P2, the `OrderByDescending` + `First` selects the group with the highest values.

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate into a collection, e.g.

```
var keysForMaxP1 = dict.Aggregate(
                       new { Max = double.MinVal, Keys = new List<int>()},
                       (state, entry) => {
                           if (entry.Value.P1 > state.Max) {
                               state.Max = entry.Value.P1;
                               state.Keys = new List<int>() { entry.Key };
                           } else if (entry.Value.P1 == state.Max) {
                               state.Keys.Add(entry.Key);
                           }
                           return state;
                       }, state => state.Keys);
```

(Untested, brain-compiled code). If you're going to do something complex like this twice, though, it might be worth commonising them by using a lambda to select the P1 from the structure. (It might also be simplest to just write a loop to do this at this point rather than trying to shoe-horn this into an Aggregate - I don't expect any ORM can do anything with this other than just exectute it in C#.)